# Cannot login with Kohana 3.3.0 ORM Auth

Tags: kohana, kohana-orm, kohana-auth

I am trying to use the Auth module with ORM driver in Kohana 3.3.0, but the only thing I can do is insert new users in the database. I can't login with them.

I started with a blank Kohana project, a simple route, the database config file, and I imported the auth SQL schema included in the ORM module (with no other table). I did not create a new model file for the users.

Here is the config file I copied to my app path/config directory:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct access allowed.');

return array(

        'driver'       => 'ORM',
        'hash_method'  => 'sha256',
        'hash_key'     => 'secretkey',
        'lifetime'     => 1209600,
        'session_type' => Session::$default,
        'session_key'  => 'auth_user',
        'users'        => array()

);
```

Now here is my simple controller. I try to load the user into te database, then login with this same user.

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_User extends Controller {

    public function action_index(){

        // Enter a new user manually
        $user = ORM::factory('user');
        $user->username = 'mylogin';
        $user->password = 'mypassword';
        $user->email = 'me@email.fr';

        try{
            $user->save();
        }
        catch(ORM_Validation_Exception $e){
            $errors = $e->errors();
        }

        if(isset($errors)){
            $this->response->body(var_dump($errors));
        }else{

            // Login with this user
            $success = Auth::instance()->login('mylogin','mypassword');
            if ($success){
                $this->response->body("Welcome !");
            }else{
                $this->response->body("Not welcome...");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This controller fails to log in. But when I check my database, I see the user is properly saved with the password hashed. Did I forgot something about my configuration ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every user must have a `login` role:

```
...
$user->save();
$user->add('roles', ORM::factory('role')->where('name', '=', 'login')->find());
```