# Kohana 3.3: Auth Module - Able to login with false password

Tags: kohana, kohana-auth

I'm having two issue with Kohana Auth module:

1. Able to login with false password
2. I have logout from the application, but when click on Back button in browser, it display the content of the secured side. Then I refresh that page, it's redirect to login page - which this redirect I need it when user click on Back button in browser.

What I have done so far:

1. I've create a workaround to check manually the password equality instead of using built-in login method and if success, use the Kohana Auth predefined method.
2. I've done checking the Session value using Firebug, it's changing when I logout. Which suppose if clicking on Back button won't display the secured side as I've an ACL implement on the pages.

Hopes anyone can help me on this...really a critical request..

Some of my reference:

1. [Cannot login with Kohana 3.3.0 ORM Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893326/cannot-login-with-kohana-3-3-0-orm-auth)
2. http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/comment/78699#Comment_78699
3. http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/11756/kohana-auth-module-3-3/p1

Regards,
Nas

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:
Register action:

```
$extra_rules = Validation::factory($this->request->post())
                        ->rule('password', 'not_empty')
                        ->rule('password', 'min_length', array(':value', '8'))
                        ->rule('password_confirm', 'matches', array(':validation', 'password_confirm', 'password'))

                $user->create($extra_rules);
//if You want to enable login add a role, or You can put it later on account confirmation or something
                if ($user->saved()) {
                    $user->add('roles', 1);
                }
```

Login action:

```
$logged = Auth::instance()->login($this->request->post('username'), $this->request->post('password'), $_POST['autologin'] = true);

        if ($logged == true) {
            $user = Auth::instance()->get_user();
            $userId = $user->id;

            HTTP::redirect('somewhere');
        } else {
            $validation = Validation::factory($this->request->post())
                    ->rule('username', 'not_empty')
                    ->rule('password', 'not_empty');
            if ($validation->check()) {
                $validation->error('username', 'general');
            }
```

Comment: where should I add the first part? I believe the 2nd part is in the controller that validate the login credential.

Comment: just gone through on some research on 1st part. that part seems for form with password & password confirm input provided. What I required is the comparison between password given with the on in database. <pre>Similar to <code>ORM::factory('User')->where('username','=',$username)->where('password','=',$hashedpassword)->find();</code></pre>

Comment: Just read the example given in [link](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/security/validation), seems that the validation is based on input givens..how can I add validation for matches to be match with value in database instead of having two input(like password & password confirm)?

Comment: Theese two inputs are only for registration purpose. User enter password an repeat it. Then password is validated to check if the password and repeat are the same.

Comment: Password from input is compared with databasepassword by auth module when $logged=Auth::instance()->login($this->request->post('username'), $this->request->post('password'), $_POST['autologin'] = true); is executed. Then $logged is true or false.

Comment: I'm using $logged=Auth::instance()->login($this->request->post('username'), $this->request->post('password'), $_POST['autologin'] = true); but always it's returned true...any ideas?